# Postgres local procedure or local module

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

I'm porting a stored procedure from Oracle to Postgres 11.
The procedure has a local procedure created inside it and being used multiple times.
I tried creating the same in Postgres but I'm not able to do so.

Is this option not available in Postgres? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that doesn't exist in PostgreSQL.

But it shouldn't be a problem to make a regular top-level function or procedure out of the nested one.